# Cant update libcurl centos6.2(64)

Tags: linux, centos

When I try to update it I get this error:

```
Transaction Check Error:
file /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4 conflicts between attempted installs of curl-7.20.0-1.el5.x86_64 and libcurl-7.19.7-26.el6_2.4.x86_64
```

Comment: You need to decide if you're running EL5 or EL6.

Answer (score 2):

As Ignacio points out, there's some conflict between "el5" (Enterprise Linux 5, i.e. RHEL5) and "el6" packages here.  You can double-check what version of CentOS you have in `/etc/redhat-release` or `/etc/issue`.  The rpm that provided your installed `/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4` can be checked with:

```
rpm -qf rpm -qf /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4
```

All this should hopefully point out that you really are running CentOS 6.2, and that `libcurl.so.4` is from an "el6" variety of package.

Then the question is how your attempted update decided you needed something from el5.  A standard first step might be to do:

```
yum clean all
yum update
```

and see if you get the same problem.  If so, how about seeing if there are any installed packages with "el5" (maybe installed manually with `rpm` instead of with `yum`?):

```
rpm -qa |grep el5
```

Could be some need to be removed, and replaced with updated versions for CentOS 6.

Comment: Thanks for an actually helpful response. I will check it out and report back.

Comment: When I do the `yum update` I end up getting this error: `Error: Package: python-ethtool-0.6-2.el5.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: python(abi) = 2.4
           Installed: python-2.6.6-29.el6.x86_64 (@base)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python26-2.6.5-6.el5.x86_64 (epel)
               python(abi) = 2.6
           Available: python31-3.1.4-1.ius.el5.x86_64 (ius)
               python(abi) = 3.1
`

Comment: Looks like when you installed [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), you picked the wrong system and architecture...

Comment: @Charles is there a way to fix this or should I just reinstall the OS?

Comment: You're going to need to find and remove all packages you installed from EPEL, and the EPEL repo itself.  The `rpm` command given by Lars is one way to find those packages. `yum list installed | grep -i epel` is another.